# Attacking synchronized clock protocol (Kerberos)

Tags: security, networking, cryptography, kerberos

If we assume that an attacker is able to control the clock of Alice, Bob, and the KDC (key distribution center) how could the attacker attack the Kerberos protocol?

Answer (score 5):

A [detailed analysis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-weber-krb-wg-kerberos-clock-synchronization-01.html) of this was done in 2003 by Joel Weber.